# Console log with if statement if option is equal to 'Gel'

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to `console.log` the option which is located in `data()` is equal to 'Gel' I tried if statement but not seem to work

any ideas ?

```js
data(){
    return {
        author: '',
        authors: ['Gel','shit']
    }
},
mounted(){
    this.shiiit()
},
shiiit:function(){
    if(this.author === 'Gel'){
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('haha')
    }
}
```

```html
<select v-model="author">
    <option v-for="author in authors" v-bind:key="author.id">
        {{ author }}
    </option>
</select>is equal to
```

Comment: You currently don't have any `author` key that has the value `Gel`.

Comment: You're disabling the console with es-lint, so it won't print to console

Comment: @Still_learning That's not the problem( my console works fine btw)

Comment: What's the `// eslint-disable-next-line no-console` for then?

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console

Comment: @Still_learning My ESlint config is changed and without that comment console doesn't work

Comment: Try `// custom console` instead

Comment: @Still_learning As I said, my console works fine and that's not my problem what you're saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the following.

The flow of the page rendering process is:

1. Mount Component
2. Render HTML **AND** execute `shiiit()`
   **-> at this point this.author is empty!**
   When you now select the author "Gel" in the select box, nothing happens.
   Take a look at watchers, there you find your solution:

   (...)
   watch: {
   author: function(newAuthor, oldAuthor){
   if(this.author === 'Gel'){
   // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
   console.log('haha')
   }
   }
   }
   (...)

[VueJS Watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)

Comment: I get ''newAuthor' is defined but never used" and ''oldAuthor' is defined but never used' can you help me ?

Comment: You can simply remove the arguments to the function, it will work fine.